# Print JSON requests/responses for each JAX-RS service

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have some JAX-RS web services with method signatures like below. Is it possible to print out the raw JSON requests coming from the clients and raw JSON response returned to the clients?

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response XXX(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Parameters requestParameters) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For returning json `return Response.ok(returnedJsonString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();`

Comment: You have misunderstood my requirement. I want to PRINT out the JSON requests that are coming from the clients, and PRINT out the JSON responses that are returned to the clients. For example, if the client sent { "x":"123" }, then I want to be able to print out this exact string, for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done via request filter for you. This is my implementation:

```
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloResource {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloResource.class);

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test(String body) {
        Map<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<>();
        tmp.put("test", "value");
        return Response.ok(tmp).build();
    }

}
```

The resource for testing. Just takes the body as a string.

Now you can register a ContainerResponseFilter and a ContainerRequestFilter.

These filters will be called before and after the request. Before will print the incoming body, after will print the response body.

It is important to not do both in the response filter because the request entity Stream is closed at the time the response filter is executed.

That is when you want to print your bodies, e.g. like this:

```
public class PrintFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter, ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {


        System.out.println("Response body: " + responseContext.getEntity());
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String string = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream());
        System.out.println("request body: " + string);
    }


}
```

I am using apache-commons to read the request Stream into a String.

For my json file, looking like that:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ cat 1.json 
{
  "eventType": 1,
  "params": {
    "field1" : 10
  }
}
```

I can make a curl, looking like this:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ curl -XPOST "localhost:9085/api/test/test" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @1.json 
{"test":"value"}
```

Which will print to my console:

```
request body: {  "eventType": 1,  "params": {    "field1" : 10  }}
Response body: {test=value}
```

That is obviously only one of many solutions. This would work for all json content types (and frankly most other content types as well I would expect).

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: Thanks pandaadb. Your request part works fine for me. For the response part, it is not logging the exact JSON response. I actually doubt that it is possible to log the exact JSON response to client. Anyway, the request logging is more important to me and your solution is good enough.

Comment: Hi @user3573403 please make sure that after you consume the INputstream in your filter and print it, you set it back to the request. A stream can only be read once and you might need to create a new stream for the request to use after you read it. Please debug and make sure the resource is retrieving what you expect!